# Value of type 'StorageReference' has no member 'data'?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to implement a photo picker into my app. For some reason I receive the following errors in two functions, Value of type 'StorageReference' has no member 'data' and Value of type 'StorageReference' has no member 'put'. Here is my code. I am honestly not sure what the problem seems to be. Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
import UIKit

import FirebaseStorage
import Photos
class AlbumViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    var id: String = ""
let picker = UIImagePickerController()

    @IBOutlet weak var image1: UIImageView!
    let storage = Storage.storage()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = id
        picker.delegate = self as! UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate
        showPhoto()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //confirm
    func confirm() {
        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Firebase Storage", message: "Image Uploaded", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


  //retrive pictures
    @IBAction func accessAlbum(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        picker.allowsEditing = false
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        picker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
        picker.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        picker.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = sender

    }
    //for image size
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        print(info)

        var selectedImageFromPicker: UIImage?

        if let editedImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage
        {
            selectedImageFromPicker = editedImage
        }else if let originalImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage{
            selectedImageFromPicker = originalImage
        }

        if let selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker
        {
            image1.image = selectedImage.resizedImageWithinRect(rectSize: CGSize(width: 300, height: 300))
            image1.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit //3

        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }




    @IBAction func savePic(_ sender: Any) {
        var data = Data()
        data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1.image!)! as Data
        // set upload path
        let imageName = "Photos/" + id + ".png"

        // ----  Upload the image to firebase storage
        let storageRef = storage.reference(withPath: imageName)
        let metaData = StorageMetadata()
        metaData.contentType = "image/png"
        storageRef.put(data, metadata: metaData){(metaData,error) in //ERROR HERE
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }else{
                self.confirm()
            }
        }
    }

    func showPhoto() {
        let imageName = "Photos/" + id + ".png"

        // Create a storage reference  path with image name

        let storageRef = storage.reference(withPath: imageName)

        storageRef.data(withMaxSize: 3 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) // ERROR HERE-> Void in
            // Create a UIImage, add it to the array
            if let imgData = data {
                let image = UIImage(data: imgData)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.myImageView.image = image
                }
                //

            } else {
                print ("no image data")
            }

        }
    }






}
extension UIImage {

    /// Returns a image that fills in newSize
    func resizedImage(newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        // Guard newSize is different
        guard self.size != newSize else { return self }

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0);
        // self.drawInRect(CGRect(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height))
        self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
        let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage
    }

    /// Returns a resized image that fits in rectSize, keeping it's aspect ratio
    /// Note that the new image size is not rectSize, but within it.
    func resizedImageWithinRect(rectSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let widthFactor = size.width / rectSize.width
        let heightFactor = size.height / rectSize.height

        var resizeFactor = widthFactor
        if size.height > size.width {
            resizeFactor = heightFactor
        }

        let newSize = CGSize(width: size.width/resizeFactor, height: size.height/resizeFactor)

        // CGSize(size.width/resizeFactor, size.height/resizeFactor)
        let resized = resizedImage(newSize: newSize)
        return resized
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[StorageReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/StorageReference) has no methods called `put` or `data`.

Perhaps you were trying to use [putData](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/StorageReference#-putdatametadata) and [getData](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/StorageReference#/c:objc(cs)StorageReference(im)dataWithMaxSize:completion:)?

Comment: Literally just tried that before checking here. That seemed to do it. Thanks!